# UIViewPrintFormatter Inserting Extra Spacing for UIWebView Content

Tags: ios, printing

I am utilizing a UIViewPrintFormatter to help me render HTML content from a UIWebView into a PDF context (and I am creating multiple columns for the content).  Everything seems to work well except for the fact that the UIViewPrintFormatter seems to be inserting 'extra' spacing wherever it sees fit (and I can't even seem to exactly determine why it is).  I am using a custom UIPrintPageRenderer.

From what I can tell, the extra spacing is all happening within the print formatter class.  I am getting the rect from the print formatter in this manner:

```
CGRect formatterRect = [formatter rectForPageAtIndex:column];
```

I am then using that rect in the following manner (only having modified the origin's x value to support the columns:

```
[self.printTask.formatter drawInRect:renderRect forPageAtIndex:i];
```

You can see in the example below that extra spacing is being inserted (see the red rectangles that I added).

Has anyone seen this or know of a way to fix this?  I obviously know that I can re-create the same by adding and positioning each item and skipping the HTML / UIWebView all together (and that will probably be what I do if I can't get this to work).

[image]

Comment: Can you identify which part of the HTML (e.g which tag) is causing the insertion of the spaces ?

Comment: In this case, it is different each time.  In some cases it is before a p tag and in some cases it is after one.  In some cases it is before a div tag.  I tested by taking the HTML it generated and loading it through Chrome and printing.  This resulted in no extra spacing, so I am assuming it is not an issue with the HTML (although it obviously wasn't multi-column like the output here).

Comment: This isn't very helpful, but I found UIPrintFormatter extremely flaky in general. Have you tried looking at this framework which I eventually had success with ? https://github.com/iclems/iOS-htmltopdf/blob/master/NDHTMLtoPDF.h

Comment: I have seen that framework, but the flexibility I am looking for it does not provide.  I am leaning toward manually drawing every object in the context and eliminating HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, I found no way to solve this issue using public methods (or private ones for that matter).  If you have a similar challenge, I would recommend leveraging TextKit / CoreText to ensure that the formatting meets your needs.